# Issue with React+Material-UI Textfield defaultValue in IE 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have issue with react + material-ui:

```js
<TextField required={settings.introTextValidation}
  className={classes.multilineField}
  multiline
  rows="5"
  defaultValue={teaser.text}
  onChange={handleChange} />
```

In ie default value is not rendered, tried static text but nothing is rendered.
Has anyone faced same issue?

Using: "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.0",

Comment: In material ui [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/) you can see that defaultValue is working properly.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?